# The characters are out of the form and it reminds me that "Overfull \vbox (16.44144pt too high)", I don't know why

Tags: tables, multirow, makecell

I'm curious about a mistake that I have made. I wrote like this:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{multirow,makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|c|r|}
    \hline
    \multirowcell{3}{ge\\ke\\cheng\\ji} & 78 \\
    \cline{2-2} & 82 \\ \cline{2-2}
    & 86 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But I could only get a form like this:

[image]

The "ji" is out of the form and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

You declared `\multirowcell{3}` but you have four rows of content inside. Yet on the right side you have 3 rows, so there is a mismatch.

Compare with:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|r|}
    \hline
    \multirowcell{4}{ge\\ke\\cheng\\ji} & 78 \\
    \cline{2-2} & 82 \\ \cline{2-2}
    & 86 \\ \cline{2-2}
    & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

which gives:

[image]